# Is there a way to save a MySQL connection for later use?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So, my situation is this. I need to import large mysql dumps into a Database using a PHP script and AJAX calls.

I have written a recursive AJAX function, which is communicating with the PHP script and sending back-an-forth all the necessary data(like position of pointer in the .sql file) to cut the next chunk from the .sql file and run it until the script reaches the end of the file.

The problem I am encountering is, that some mysql dumps have let's say variables defined in the beginning of the file and are using them later in the file. If these 2 segments of code are not in the same chunk, I am getting a SQL error, because the variables used are not defined.

So generally, I wonder, if there's a way to store the connection/state of the session, to restore it later and be able to use session variables.

Thank you!

Comment: Depending on your php setup you may also make use of [connection pooling with the mysqlnd php extension](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd-ms.pooling.php), some servers already have that extension enabled by default. Just read the documentation, you don't need to change something in your php scripts to make use of it.

Comment: I also found this to be interesting in your case: [The mysqli Extension and Persistent Connections](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php)

Comment: @xander I just checked and it seems like most shared hostings don't support the mysqlnd extension. Persistent connections just speed up the part of connecting with the server in some cases, they don't save any relevant session data in my case.

Comment: you might be right, it's a safety feature in the clean up code. The doc states "Reset session variables", to bad in your case, but maybe it can be disabled without recompiling the mysqli extension itself. Because it says `It is possible to switch off the automatic cleanup code, by compiling PHP with MYSQLI_NO_CHANGE_USER_ON_PCONNECT defined`..

Comment: Sound like you are using AJAX for the wrong purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Only if you make your PHP script persistent. In a general HTTP setup, each call to PHP creates a new PHP instance which is torn down when the request ends. That necessarily ends that MySQL session and any temporary data you have created during that request.

You can write a persistent worker in PHP which runs indefinitely and answers request from some sort of message bus, say [Gearman](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gearman.php), [ØMQ](http://zeromq.org) or [Crossbar](https://crossbar.io). So a request would go something like:

```
browser ⇄ web server ⇄ ephemeral PHP instance ⇄ Gearman ⇄ persistent PHP worker
```

In that persistent worker, you can persist anything you want. That obviously requires a bit of a special server setup and won't be possible on generic shared hosting and such.

Comment: The script is part of a commercial plugin, which purpose it is to restore backuped websites. So I would definitely need it to work on generic hostings, but anyway thanks for the info!